# Leer response de un json array en vb.net

Tags: vb.net

El problema que tengo es el siguiente tengo un response de un json que es el siguiente:

```
{
    "response": {
        "trace": {
            "serviceId": "api-prueba-val",
            "consumerId": "apiew",
            "channelCode": "api",
            "traceId": "1552555555521552585874515452855512"
        },
        "payload": {
            "ideCotizacion": "748415414241558545232",
            "listRptaCalculoPrima": [
                {
                    "indValidacion": 0,
                    "ideProd": 4750,
                    "descProd": "PRUEBA DAC",
                    "idpMoneda": "SOL",
                    "codBroker": 47,
                    "codAgencia": "1",
                    "fecIniVig": "2020-03-18",
                    "fecFinVig": "2020-03-31",
                    "idpFormaPago": "A",
                    "periodo": 2,
                    "porcComision": 0,
                    "porcDerechoEmision": "0.01",
                    "primaMinima": 200,
                    "primaEndoso": 40,
                    "indFormaLq": "P",
                    "indFormaCta": "P",
                    "indLq": "S",
                    "cliente": {
                        "codCliente": 152501,
                        "tipoDocumento": "1",
                        "numeroDocumento": "45850214589",
                        "nombre": "PRUEBA DAC S.A.C",
                        "apeMaterno": "PRUEBA DAC S.A.C",
                        "apePaterno": "PRUEBA DAC S.A.C",
                        "codDepartamento": "018",
                        "codDistrito": "020",
                        "codPais": "520",
                        "codProvincia": "018",
                        "codUbigeo": "5201",
                        "correo": "prueba@hotmail.com",
                        "departamento": "Lima",
                        "direccion": "AV.PRUEBA",
                        "distrito": "PRUEBA",
                        "estCivil": "S",
                        "codCiiu": "B142536",
                        "fecNacimiento": "1989-10-06",
                        "provincia": "PRUEBA",
                        "sexo": "M",
                        "telefono": "1458963",
                        "indCorreo": "S"
                    },
                    "sucursales": [
                        {
                            "nroSucursal": 1,
                            "dscSucursal": "PRUEBA",
                            "nroTrabajadores": 5,
                            "montoPlanilla": 15000,
                            "ideActividadRiesgo": 7,
                            "dscActividadRiesgo": "descActi",
                            "idpNivelRiesgo": "6",
                            "dscNivelRiesgo": "descNivel",
                            "indValidacion": 0,
                            "tasa": 6,
                            "PrimaFinalxSede": "50.00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "igvFinal": "10.20",
                    "deremision": "4.00",
                    "montoPrimaFinal": 257.54,
                    "mensajeInformativo": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "status": {
            "success": true
        }
    }
}
```

Este mi código en vb.net:

La lectura se realiza de forma correcta hasta el código que no esta comentado la variable osubitem2 As Object (el ultimo es un JObject) cuando ese JObject lo cambio por JProperty y al osubitem3 lo cambio por JObject no me deja entrar a la matriz "sucursales" que es donde necesito ingresar para leer lo datos que hay dentro.

```
Dim ob As JObject = JObject.Parse(vStrResultado)
        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = ob.Children().ToList
        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            Select Case item.Name
                Case "response"
                    For Each subitem As JProperty In item.Values
                        subitem.CreateReader()
                        Select Case subitem.Name
                            Case "payload"
                                For Each osubitem1 As JProperty In subitem.Values
                                    osubitem1.CreateReader()
                                    Select Case osubitem1.Name
                                        Case "listRptaCalculoPrima"
                                            For Each osubitem2 As JObject In osubitem1.Values
                                                osubitem2.CreateReader()
                                                Session("montoPrimaFinal") = osubitem2("montoPrimaFinal")
                                                Session("igvFinal") = osubitem2("igvFinal")


                                                'Select Case osubitem2.Name
                                                '    Case "sucursales"
                                                '        For Each osubitem3 As JObject In osubitem2.Values
                                                '            osubitem3.CreateReader()
                                                '            'OBTENER DATOS DE LA LISTA DE SUCURSALES


                                                '        Next
                                                'End Select
                                            Next
                                    End Select
                                Next
                                Exit For
                        End Select
                    Next
                    Exit For
            End Select
        Next
```

psdt: Comparen el response con la estructura del código de la estructura de vb.net

Comment: porque no lo haces simplemente con NewtonSoft?

Comment: @RamiroBarone cual sería la forma de hacerlo con NewtonSoft en vb.net?

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Descarga la libreria Newtowsfot desde Nuget, luego deberias tener tus clases generadas.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Donde recibis tu json y tenes el string puedes hacer asi:

```
var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MiClase>(json);
```

Genere las clases basadas en tu json en el siguiente sitio:

> http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class Trace
{
    public string serviceId { get; set; }
    public string consumerId { get; set; }
    public string channelCode { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public int codCliente { get; set; }
    public string tipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string numeroDocumento { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apeMaterno { get; set; }
    public string apePaterno { get; set; }
    public string codDepartamento { get; set; }
    public string codDistrito { get; set; }
    public string codPais { get; set; }
    public string codProvincia { get; set; }
    public string codUbigeo { get; set; }
    public string correo { get; set; }
    public string departamento { get; set; }
    public string direccion { get; set; }
    public string distrito { get; set; }
    public string estCivil { get; set; }
    public string codCiiu { get; set; }
    public string fecNacimiento { get; set; }
    public string provincia { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }
    public string telefono { get; set; }
    public string indCorreo { get; set; }
}

public class Sucursale
{
    public int nroSucursal { get; set; }
    public string dscSucursal { get; set; }
    public int nroTrabajadores { get; set; }
    public int montoPlanilla { get; set; }
    public int ideActividadRiesgo { get; set; }
    public string dscActividadRiesgo { get; set; }
    public string idpNivelRiesgo { get; set; }
    public string dscNivelRiesgo { get; set; }
    public int indValidacion { get; set; }
    public int tasa { get; set; }
    public string PrimaFinalxSede { get; set; }
}

public class ListRptaCalculoPrima
{
    public int indValidacion { get; set; }
    public int ideProd { get; set; }
    public string descProd { get; set; }
    public string idpMoneda { get; set; }
    public int codBroker { get; set; }
    public string codAgencia { get; set; }
    public string fecIniVig { get; set; }
    public string fecFinVig { get; set; }
    public string idpFormaPago { get; set; }
    public int periodo { get; set; }
    public int porcComision { get; set; }
    public string porcDerechoEmision { get; set; }
    public int primaMinima { get; set; }
    public int primaEndoso { get; set; }
    public string indFormaLq { get; set; }
    public string indFormaCta { get; set; }
    public string indLq { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public List<Sucursale> sucursales { get; set; }
    public string igvFinal { get; set; }
    public string deremision { get; set; }
    public double montoPrimaFinal { get; set; }
    public List<object> mensajeInformativo { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public string ideCotizacion { get; set; }
    public List<ListRptaCalculoPrima> listRptaCalculoPrima { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Trace trace { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
}

public class MiClase
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```